# Passign the "key" "values" from JSON object to perl script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, perl

I am trying to build a shopping cart application. I have all the items in shopping cart inside a javascript object called Cart. Data in Cart is of the form {"sku"=quantity} For example.

```
     Cart={"5x123"=1,"5x125"=3}
```

Now I have a form which accepts shipping and billing address.

```
 <form method="post" action="/perl/xxxx/echo.cgi"> 
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Shipping Address:</td>
        <td><Input type="text" name="address" id="saddress" size="40" /></td>
    </tr>
    ....
    <tr>
        <td><input type="reset" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit Order"/></td>
    </tr>  
    </table>
   </form>
```

When I submit this form I need to store "sku" and "quantity" from Javascript Object Cart into DB using perl.

Could someone please tell me the easiest way to do this?

Should I ajax or hidden values in form?

If I use ajax, then how to retrieve values from Cart inside perlscript?

If I use hidden values this way

```
    <input type=hidden name=sku value="">
     //How to populate value field
    //I need to have as many hidden fields as the number of items in cart
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX in the browser to submit your JavaScript object to the server.  The [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) javascript library is excellent for helping you here.

Then, use the [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.63/lib/CGI.pm) perl module in your cgi to retrieve the posted values, and the [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm) module (as previously mentioned) to transform the JSON object to a perl hash.

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty new to AJAX and JQuery. Here is the AJAX call I created.     $(':submit').on('click',function(e){
  if(!validate_fields_on_submit()) {
              e.preventDefault();
              return;
             } 
       $.ajax({
         dataType : 'text', // the datatype you are returning
         url: '/perl/xxxx/store.cgi',
   data:Cart,
               success:function (msg){ // data is the data returned from the ajax call
          handle.innerHTML = msg;
  
      } 
     
   });  Is this right?

Comment: difficult to check syntax when it's in a comment like that, but the parts all seem to be there.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect ajax is the way to go.  To read your Cart json object in Perl, use the [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm) module, specifically decode_json. It'll convert your data into a perl-friendly hash, which you can then reference as needed.